# Apache POI not updating values

Tags: java, arrays, apache, for-loop, apache-poi

So I have this code that is supposed to reformat an Excel spreadsheet. Essentially what I am doing is iterating through each row and cell, and when I find a cell with the right keyword I store the value from the 14th cell in that row. I have to make multiple passes through this loop, and I'm running into the issue that the values are not updating the second time through. Say I get -12, 2, and 10 for my 3 values at first. When I run through the loop again, the names update in the array output, but the values I pull from the spreadsheet do not change. This seems like it ought to be a pretty simple fix, but I can't seem to figure out where the error in my code is.

When I run my code with the variables "Labor Encapsulation" and "Factory Burden", these are the results I get:

[Labor Encapsulation Standard, Labor Encapsulation Actual, Jun-18, -277222.49, 369647.55, -91020.59]
[Factory Burden Standard, Factory Burden Actual, Jun-18, -277222.49, 369647.55, -91020.59]

The first part of my code is simply formatting the array and reading in the variables I want to take in. While I believe the error is in the final while loop, I'm not entirely sure if this could be fixed with declaring the arrays in a different spot. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Main {
static XSSFRow row;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("Production Costs Update.xlsx"));
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
     XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
     Iterator < Row >  rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("How many variables are you adding to the spreadsheet?");
     int num = scan.nextInt();
     scan.nextLine();
     String[] nameArray = new String[num];
     String[] dataArray = new String[6];

     for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++)
     {
         System.out.println("Enter the next variable: ");
         nameArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
     }


     for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++)
     {
         String name = nameArray[i];
         dataArray[0] = name + " Standard";
         dataArray[1] = name + " Actual";

         LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

         int month = today.getMonthValue();
         int year = today.getYear();
         String monthAB = "";
         if(month == 1)
             monthAB = "Jan";
         if(month == 2)
             monthAB = "Feb";
         if(month == 3)
             monthAB = "Mar";
         if(month == 4)
             monthAB = "Apr";
         if(month == 5)
             monthAB = "May";
         if(month == 6)
             monthAB = "Jun";
         if(month == 7)
             monthAB = "Jul";
         if(month == 8)
             monthAB = "Aug";
         if(month == 9)
             monthAB = "Sep";
         if(month == 10)
             monthAB = "Oct";
         if(month == 11)
             monthAB = "Nov";
         if(month == 12)
             monthAB = "Dec";


         String date = monthAB + "-" + (year-2000);

         dataArray[2] = date;


         while(rowIterator.hasNext())
         {
             row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
             Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
             while(cellIterator.hasNext())
             {
                 Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                 if(cell.getCellTypeEnum()==CellType.STRING)
                 {
                     if(cell.getStringCellValue().contains(nameArray[i]))
                     {
                         if(cell.getStringCellValue().contains("Standard"))
                         {
                             dataArray[3] =  String.valueOf(row.getCell(14).getNumericCellValue());
                         }
                         if(cell.getStringCellValue().contains("Actual"))
                         {
                             dataArray[4] = String.valueOf(row.getCell(14).getNumericCellValue());
                         }
                         if(cell.getStringCellValue().contains("Variance"))
                         {
                             dataArray[5] = String.valueOf(row.getCell(14).getNumericCellValue());
                         }
                     }

                 }
             }



         }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataArray));
     }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the iterator only once before your loop over `nameArray`.  As a result, when you try to scan for the second variable, the row iterator is empty. Since you want to re-scan the rows, you should move the following line to inside the `for` loop:

```
Iterator <Row>  rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
```

Or just use the enhanced for loop

```
for (Row row : spreadsheet) {
....
}
```